# meteor: show alert on created user

Tags: meteor, user-accounts

I want to show to the user a message like: "I have sent a email to activate your account".

I cannot because when the user has been created I have not found a hook for this.

Do you know some way to do this?

I currently show a message permanently, but I don't want this way. I just want to show once when user is singed up.

Comment: where do you create users, from client or server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are 2 options here, if you are creating the user on the client side, just use

```
Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: password}, function(err) {
 if(!err){
   alert(""I have sent a email to activate your account")
  }
});
```

Or if you are creating the user from a method, it should look like this.

```
//Server.js
    Meter.method({
     createUser:function(username,email,password){
       //create user logic.
      }
    })
```

And on the client it should look like this.

```
Meteor.call('createUser',username,email,password,function(err,result){
  if(!err){
   alert(""I have sent a email to activate your account")
  }
});
```

On both cases we are using an extra parameter, named `callback` this function,  accept 2 other parameters  wich are `err,result`, so if there is not error when the accounts its created, the alert should be triggered

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to add the alert in the callback from createUser() on the client.  Assuming you have something like a form that you submit to create the user, then you would do ...

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'submit #new-user-form': function(event) { 
    // These next few lines will depend on what your template looks like and what data you require on login
    // Here I've assumed just username and pw in appropriately-named inputs on your page
    var email = $('#email-input').val();
    var password = $('#password-input').val();
    event.preventDefault();

    Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: password}, function(error) { 
      if (error) { alert("There was an error!"); }
      else { alert("I have sent you an email to verify your account"); }
    });
  }
});
```

If you want to accomplish this behavior with accounts-ui installed, [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_ui_config) doesn't show anything you can hook into.  However, you can do it manually like so:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click .login-form-create-account #login-buttons-password': function() { 
    alert("I sent you an email to verify your account");
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, that will still fire even if the user was not successfully created.